# Decode String in an unknown format

Tags: string, utf-8

I have a string returned in this format:

```
\n\bbcn_test\u0012\u00041.14\u001a\u0004escc\"\u0004vscc*(\u0012\f\u0012\n\b\u0001\u0012\u0002\b\u0000\u0012\u0002\b\u0001\u001a\u000b\u0012\t\n\u0007Org1MSP\u001a\u000b\u0012\t\n\u0007Org2MSP2D\n \ufffd\ufffda\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd3RU4\ufffd\ufffdR\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd@\ufffd\ufffds\b\ufffd\u0014\ufffd\ufffd.\ufffd!\ufffd\u0012 s\ufffd\ufffdc\ufffd6\ufffd\ufffd@\ufffd\u001eF\ufffdƳ\ufffdi\ufffd$\ufffd\ufffd4\ufffdgP\ufffd:\ufffdt\u000e: 6ђ\ufffd\ufffd3\u007fJ\ufffdHt\u0004\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd^{\\\ufffd\u001d\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd3\ufffdb?@\ufffdB,\u0012\f\u0012\n\b\u0001\u0012\u0002\b\u0000\u0012\u0002\b\u0001\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org1MSP\u0010\u0001\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org2MSP\u0010\u0001

\n\u0004mycc\u0012\u00031.0\u001a\u0004escc\"\u0004vscc*,\u0012\f\u0012\n\b\u0002\u0012\u0002\b\u0000\u0012\u0002\b\u0001\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org1MSP\u0010\u0003\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org2MSP\u0010\u00032D\n \ufffd\u0011}\ufffdT\ufffdV \u0010l\ufffdNT\ufffd\ufffdz\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdv+\ufffd˹5;\ufffd@q\ufffd\ufffd\u000e\u0012 \u0007\u001f\u0014)\u001e\u0015+\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdt\ufffd\u0013ak\ufffd\u0015J\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdZ\u0017_c&: y\ufffd\ufffdw\ufffdnN\ufffd<\ufffd3^v\ufffdbIB`M\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd)&\u0007x\ufffd;(u\ufffdLB,\u0012\f\u0012\n\b\u0001\u0012\u0002\b\u0000\u0012\u0002\b\u0001\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org1MSP\u0010\u0001\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org2MSP\u0010\u0001
```

I am trying to decode it in order to obtain a valid string but I don't understand which format it's written in and what is a good decoder for it.

How can I determine what the format is and how to decode it?

Comment: What you've written here is a valid string (we know that because our web browsers can display it easily). What do you believe the decoded string should be? If you believe this is an encoding, why do you believe it encodes a readable string (to me it looks like binary data, not character data)? Where did you get this data? The API should tell you what it's returning.

Comment: BTW, this looks exactly like a TLV (Type-Length-Value) format. The first byte is a type 0x0a, followed by a length 0x08, followed by eight bytes of data ("bcn_test"), followed by a type (0x12), followed by a length (0x04), followed by 4 bytes of data ("1.14"), etc.

Comment: Ah; probably ASN.1, I'm guessing for Hyperledger? I'd go check the protocol docs for whatever software you're using and it should explain how to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is binary data that has been stringified into a human readable format.

So, you need to first parse the string converting its characters into bytes.

Substrings that are encoded in an escape sequence format (preceded by the `'\'` character followed by 1-4 characters) are decoded to specific bytes like this:

- `\b` -> `0x08`
- `\t` -> `0x09`
- `\n` -> `0x0A`
- `\f` -> `0x0C`
- `\r` -> `0x0D`
- `\"` -> `0x22`
- `\'` -> `0x27`
- `\\` -> `0x5C`
- `\u00##` + `\uff##` -> `0x##` (the `ff` is due to sign-extension for bytes >= 0x80)

Any un-escaped characters in the string are to be converted as-is (ie, simply cast from 16-bit `Char` to 8-bit `Byte` ignoring the high 8 bits).

Let's look at the first string you provided:

> \n\bbcn_test\u0012\u00041.14\u001a\u0004escc\"\u0004vscc*(\u0012\f\u0012\n\b\u0001\u0012\u0002\b\u0000\u0012\u0002\b\u0001\u001a\u000b\u0012\t\n\u0007Org1MSP\u001a\u000b\u0012\t\n\u0007Org2MSP2D\n \ufffd\ufffda\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd3RU4\ufffd\ufffdR\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd@\ufffd\ufffds\b\ufffd\u0014\ufffd\ufffd.\ufffd!\ufffd\u0012 s\ufffd\ufffdc\ufffd6\ufffd\ufffd@\ufffd\u001eF\ufffdƳ\ufffdi\ufffd$\ufffd\ufffd4\ufffdgP\ufffd:\ufffdt\u000e: 6ђ\ufffd\ufffd3\u007fJ\ufffdHt\u0004\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd^{\\ufffd\u001d\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd3\ufffdb?@\ufffdB,\u0012\f\u0012\n\b\u0001\u0012\u0002\b\u0000\u0012\u0002\b\u0001\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org1MSP\u0010\u0001\u001a\r\u0012\u000b\n\u0007Org2MSP\u0010\u0001

Break up the individual sequences for decoding:

`\n` `\b` `b` `c` `n` `_` `t` `e` `s` `t` `\u0012` `\u0004` `1` `.` `1` `4` `\u001a` `\u0004` `e` `s` `c` `c` `\"` `\u0004` `v` `s` `c` `c` `*` `(` `\u0012` `\f` `\u0012` `\n` `\b` `\u0001` `\u0012` `\u0002` `\b` `\u0000` `\u0012` `\u0002` `\b` `\u0001` `\u001a` `\u000b` `\u0012` `\t` `\n` `\u0007` `O` `r` `g` `1` `M` `S` `P` `\u001a` `\u000b` `\u0012` `\t` `\n` `\u0007` `O` `r` `g` `2` `M` `S` `P` `2` `D` `\n`  `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `a` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `3` `R` `U` `4` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `R` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `@` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `s` `\b` `\ufffd` `\u0014` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `.` `\ufffd` `!` `\ufffd` `\u0012`  `s` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `c` `\ufffd` `6` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `@` `\ufffd` `\u001e` `F` `\ufffd` `Ƴ` `\ufffd` `i` `\ufffd` `$` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `4` `\ufffd` `g` `P` `\ufffd` `:` `\ufffd` `t` `\u000e` `:`  `6` `ђ`<sup>1</sup> `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `3` `\u007f` `J` `\ufffd` `H` `t` `\u0004` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `^` `{` `\\` `\ufffd` `\u001d` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `\ufffd` `3` `\ufffd` `b` `?` `@` `\ufffd` `B` `,` `\u0012` `\f` `\u0012` `\n` `\b` `\u0001` `\u0012` `\u0002` `\b` `\u0000` `\u0012` `\u0002` `\b` `\u0001` `\u001a` `\r` `\u0012` `\u000b` `\n` `\u0007` `O` `r` `g` `1` `M` `S` `P` `\u0010` `\u0001` `\u001a` `\r` `\u0012` `\u000b` `\n` `\u0007` `O` `r` `g` `2` `M` `S` `P` `\u0010` `\u0001`

And convert them to bytes:

`0x0A` `0x08` `0x62` `0x63` `0x6E` `0x5F` `0x74` `0x65` `0x73` `0x74` `0x12` `0x04` `0x31` `0x2E` `0x31` `0x34` `0x1A` `0x04` `0x65` `0x73` `0x63` `0x63` `0x22` `0x04` `0x76` `0x73` `0x63` `0x63` `0x2A` `0x28` `0x12` `0x0C` `0x12` `0x0A` `0x08` `0x01` `0x12` `0x02` `0x08` `0x00` `0x12` `0x02` `0x08` `0x01` `0x1A` `0x0B` `0x12` `0x09` `0x0A` `0x07` `0x4F` `0x72` `0x67` `0x31` `0x4D` `0x53` `0x50` `0x1A` `0x0B` `0x12` `0x09` `0x0A` `0x07` `0x4F` `0x72` `0x67` `0x32` `0x4D` `0x53` `0x50` `0x32` `0x44` `0x0A` `0x20` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x61` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x33` `0x52` `0x55` `0x34` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x52` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x40` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x73` `0x08` `0xFD` `0x14` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x2E` `0xFD` `0x21` `0xFD` `0x12` `0x20` `0x73` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x63` `0xFD` `0x36` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x40` `0xFD` `0x1E` `0x46` `0xFD` `0x59` `0xFD` `0x69` `0xFD` `0x24` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x34` `0xFD` `0x67` `0x50` `0xFD` `0x3A` `0xFD` `0x74` `0x0E` `0x3A` `0x20` `0x36` `ђ`<sup>1</sup> `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x33` `0x7F` `0x4A` `0xFD` `0x48` `0x74` `0x04` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x5E` `0x7B` `0x5C` `0xFD` `0x1D` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0xFD` `0x33` `0xFD` `0x62` `0x3F` `0x40` `0xFD` `0x42` `0x2C` `0x12` `0x0C` `0x12` `0x0A` `0x08` `0x01` `0x12` `0x02` `0x08` `0x00` `0x12` `0x02` `0x08` `0x01` `0x1A` `0x0D` `0x12` `0x0b` `0x0A` `0x07` `0x4F` `0x72` `0x67` `0x31` `0x4D` `0x53` `0x50` `0x10` `0x01` `0x1A` `0x0D` `0x12` `0x0B` `0x0A` `0x07` `0x4F` `0x72` `0x67` `0x32` `0x4D` `0x53` `0x50` `0x10` `0x01`

Once you have decoded the bytes, you can interpret binary data as needed.  It *appears* to be in a kind of Type-Length-Value format, like @RobNapier suggested in a comment to your question:

> BTW, this looks exactly like a TLV (Type-Length-Value) format. The first byte is a type 0x0a, followed by a length 0x08, followed by eight bytes of data ("bcn_test"), followed by a type (0x12), followed by a length (0x04), followed by 4 bytes of data ("1.14"), etc.

`0x0A` (Type 10), `0x08` (Len 8)
`0x62` `0x63` `0x6E` `0x5F` `0x74` `0x65` `0x73` `0x74` (`bcn_test`)

`0x12` (Type 18) `0x04` (Len 4)
`0x31` `0x2E` `0x31` `0x34` (`1.14`)

`0x1A` (Type 26) `0x04` (Len 4)
`0x65` `0x73` `0x63` `0x63` (`escc`)

`0x22` (Type 34) `0x04` (Len 4)
`0x76` `0x73` `0x63` `0x63` (`vscc`)

and so on ...

<sup>1: however, I'm not sure how to correctly decode the `ђ` in the original string.  It is Unicode codepoint [`U+0452 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DJE`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0452/index.htm), which in a Java `Char` is bytes `0x04 0x52`.  Truncated to `0x04` or `0x52`, or interpreted in a Cyrillic charset like Windows-1251 where it would be byte `0x90`, it doesn't match up with the rest of the TLV format.</sup>